# Remove nodes with dead end from path taken by Depth first search

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph, nodes, depth-first-search

If I console.log visited nodes, I get a ton of spare nodes that I don't want.

I just what the nodes necessary to get for start to end node (does not need to be the shortest), But I don't want all the other paths/nodes the algo took before it found the right path

```
function dfs(start, visited = new Set()) {

    console.log(start)
    
    visited.add(start);

    const destinations = adjacencyList.get(start);

    for (const destination of destinations) {

        if (destination === 'BKK') { 
            console.log(`DFS found Bangkok`)
            return;
        }
        
        if (!visited.has(destination)) {
            dfs(destination, visited);
        }

    }

}

dfs('PHX')
```

Comment: Dijkstra's Algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to track if the node `destination` you visited leads to correct path or not. Hence, you should return after exhausting a particular node whether end node can be visited through this node or not.

```
function dfs(start, visited = new Set()) {
    visited.add(start);

    const destinations = adjacencyList.get(start);
    var result = false;
    
    for (const destination of destinations) {
        
        if (destination === 'BKK') { 
            console.log(`DFS found Bangkok`);
            console.log(destination);
            return true;
        }
        
        if (!visited.has(destination)) {
             result |= dfs(destination, visited); // you can visit end from this node
        }

    }

    if(result) {
      console.log(start);
    }

    return result;
}

dfs('PHX')
```

Notice that this will print nodes from start -> finish in reverse order i.e. from finish to start.
To have path from `start ..->..finish`, you can store in some array(instead of console.log) and reverse that after dfs is complete.

Comment: I think you forgot curly braces at last, if statement. Is the return statement included?

Comment: @Mathiuscov updated. Return is not included.

Comment: Why did you use the bitwise or (|=) operator instead of a assign (=)?

Comment: @Mathiuscov because dfs(...) can return true or false, so we want to retain `true ` state if it occurs in any call. Initially result is false, if for any of the subsequent dfs calls a true is returned, return will become true and never change. That is what we expect.

Comment: @ManavChhibber You'll want to use `||=` though instead of `|=`